# Get element size in react componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, width

At componentDidMount I get only zero for offsetWidth of an element but element totally has width.

How to get an element width after render?

```
componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.$slide.offsetWidth);
  }

render() { 
return <div
          className='Reader__ImageWrapper'
          ref={(slide) => { this.$slide = slide; }}
       >
          <img src={`/Images/Reader/Pages/Page 001.jpg`} className="Reader__Image"/>
           <img src={`/Images/Reader/Pages/Page 002.jpg`} className="Reader__Image"/>
       </div>
}
```